# When you update a model's Relationship and its corresponding Column with different values, how do you control which value gets used upon commit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

so I've declared a clone method in my model, like so:

```py
def clone(self):
    valid_cols = [key for key, val in vars(type(self)).items() if isinstance(val, InstrumentedAttribute) and key not in self.__table__.primary_key.columns]
    return type(self)(**{key: getattr(self, key) for key in valid_cols})
```

Which makes it nice and easy to clone records and then update their attributes.

There's a problem though. I'm getting undesired behaviour whenever I then update a field that already had its associated relationship copied.

For example, take:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.id))

    parent = relationship(Parent, backref=Backref("children", uselist=True, cascade="all"))

    def clone(self):
        from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import InstrumentedAttribute
        valid_cols = [key for key, val in vars(type(self)).items() if isinstance(val, InstrumentedAttribute) and key not in self.__table__.primary_key.columns]
        return type(self)(**{key: getattr(self, key) for key in valid_cols})


metadata.create_all()


parent1 = Parent()
parent2 = Parent()
child1 = Child(parent=parent1)

s.add_all([parent1, parent2, child1])
s.commit()

child2 = child1.clone()
child2.parent_id = parent2.id

child2.parent_id  # 2

s.add(child2)
s.commit()

child2.parent_id  # 1
child2.parent is parent1  # True
```

So, it's pretty obvious that the expected behaviour would have been for child2's parent to be parent2, not parent1. But parent1 was set directly on the child2's 'Child.parent' relationship during the clone method, so even though child2's 'Child.parent_id' column was later set to parent2's id, the orm didn't care and discarded that update upon commit.

My question is, is there a way to get the orm to take the last modified property as the absolute truth when there's a disagreement between a relationship property and a column property?

I could avoid setting relationship properties inside the clone method, but I don't want to, because in more complex cases its incredibly useful to have access to the old object's relationships, and I also find it important in my use-case to be able to set column properties directly, rather than setting their relationship property.

I also want to do any required updates on the cloned object before commiting anything at all to the database.

Basically, is there any simple silver bullet? Any way I could modify the clone method so that, leaving everything else unchanged, at the end of the example code child2's parent will be parent2 rather than parent1?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Under SQLAlchemy 2.0, this code emits a warning when the parent is set after the call to `clone()`:

> SAWarning: Object of type  not in session, add operation along 'Parent.children' will not proceed (This warning originated from the Session 'autoflush' process, which was invoked automatically in response to a user-initiated operation.)

Adding the `child` to the session before setting `parent_id` prevents the warning and delivers the required behaviour:

```py
child2 = child1.clone()
s.add(child2)
child2.parent_id = parent2.id
```